# How to sum rows of column 'A' if text in another cell matches with column 'A' text (excel)

Tags: excel

[image]

Let's suppose this table as data, where I'd like to have another table showing the total sum for each category

[image]

What's the best approach to do this? I tried with `=SUMIF(A1:D1;Sheet1!A1;A2:A4)` but that returns 1.

EDIT: I want to clarify that my real application has almost 400 columns with 744 rows each one, so a Pivot Table would be ideal but as far as I know I would have to drag every column to values box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF/SUMIFS must have identically shaped ranges for criteria and sum. This requirement does not lend itself well to transposed ranges. Try,

```
=SUM(INDEX(F$2:I$4, 0, MATCH(A2, F$1:I$1, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula

```
=SUM(INDEX($A$1:$D$4,,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$D$1,0)))
```

[image]